# the jbi node does not exist glassfish v3 Netbeans 7.2.1

Tags: glassfish-3, netbeans-7, jbi

i cannot see JBI in services tab of my netbeans 7.2.1. I have started glassfish v3 but it only shows applications, resources and jvms.

Should I do somethings before or what ? I do some search but nothing found please help

thanks in advance

Comment: I am facing the same issue and not able to find any documentation about it. I downloaded the latest build of Glassfish 3 and installed all the shared libraries and binding components/service engines by putting all the jars in the domain1/jbi/autoinstall directory. In the log file, i see all the libs and components starting correctly after small modifications but the JBI node is not available in the glassfish admin console. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no anwsers but thanks i solved my probleme from here
https://blogs.oracle.com/vinceg/entry/installing_open_source_jbi_components

Comment: Not of any help at all as the tutorial is not available.